# MySQLでレプリケーションする際にマスターを無停止で行いたい

Tags: mysql

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/replication-howto-masterstatus.html

上記のURLを参考にレプリケーションを進めていますが、以下のコマンドを打てと書いてありました。このコマンドを打つと現在稼働しているマスターサーバーの読み込みができなくなってしまいます。

```
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
```

マスターサーバーを無停止でレプリケーションを行いたいと思っておりますが、いい方法を教えていただけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

無停止はわかりませんが 座標を確認したらすぐに `UNLOCK TABLES;` を実行してロックを開放すると元に戻ります。